# Publish without manifest

Tags: visual-studio, manifest, publish

I work on Visual Studio 2010, developing in C#.

I wonder if it is possible to specify to VS not to create the *xxx.exe.manifest* and *xxx.application* files when I publish my solution as I don't need both files to run my application (at least I don't feel that I need them, feel free to advice if I shouldn't want to eradicate them...).

Do you know if there is a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify /MANIFEST:NO on the command line for linker or disabled them in Project configuration.